# rhandsontable package no output displayed

Tags: r, shiny, cran, rhandsontable

I have used a couple of standard examples quoted for the rhandsontable package and I get no output at all. The code runs, but no output appears.

Funny, the shiny controls before and after the rhandsontable widgets do appear but no output from rhandsontable at all.

The examples (among several others tried are):

```
library(rhandsontable)

DF = data.frame(int = 1:10,
                numeric = rnorm(10),
                logical = TRUE,
                character = LETTERS[1:10],
                fact = factor(letters[1:10]),
                date = seq(from = Sys.Date(), by = "days", length.out = 10),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# add a sparkline chart
DF$chart = sapply(1:10, function(x) jsonlite::toJSON(list(values=rnorm(10))))

rhandsontable(DF, rowHeaders = NULL) %>%
  hot_col("chart", renderer = htmlwidgets::JS("renderSparkline"))
```

--  and the sessionInfo is:

```
session_info()

 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
 os       Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS          
 system   i686, linux-gnu             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language en_GB:en                    
 collate  en_GB.UTF-8                 
 tz       Europe/London               
 date     2018-01-21
```

─ Packages ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

```
 package       * version date       source        
 clisymbols      1.2.0   2017-05-21 CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 digest          0.6.12  2017-01-27 CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 htmltools       0.3.5   2016-03-21 CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 htmlwidgets     0.8     2016-11-09 CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 httpuv          1.3.3   2015-08-04 CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 jsonlite        1.3     2017-02-28 CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 magrittr        1.5     2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 mime            0.5     2016-07-07 CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 R6              2.2.0   2016-10-05 CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 Rcpp            0.12.10 2017-03-19 CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 rhandsontable * 0.3.5   2018-01-10 CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 sessioninfo   * 1.0.0   2017-06-21 CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 shiny         * 1.0.2   2017-04-18 CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 withr           1.0.2   2016-06-20 CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 xtable          1.8-2   2016-02-05 CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 yaml            2.1.14  2016-11-12 CRAN (R 3.3.3)
```

Does anyone have a pointer to what may be needed to correct this?

Comment: The code is fine. The issue is with the package itself. The dev package on github has been fixed `devtools::install_github("jrowen/rhandsontable")` Please try.

Comment: Reference: https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable/issues/212